# Camera_Info_Manager

Tags: ros, camera-info-manager, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am trying to do a bumblebee xb3 driver and I have the following problem.

I found out a driver needs to supply the service set_camera_info for stereo camera calibration, because when i run stereo calibration the output is

mike@BLACKBANDIT:~$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 right:=/xb3_short/right/image_raw left:=/xb3_short/left/image_raw right_camera:=/xb3_short/right left_camera:=/xb3_short/left
Waiting for service /xb3_short/left/set_camera_info ...
Service not found
Waiting for service /xb3_short/right/set_camera_info ...
Service not found

Hence i started looking for this service. I found in http://www.ros.org/doc/api/camera1394/html/camera1394_8cpp_source.html that we should use dynamic_reconfigure.

I also found that one should use camera_info_manager.

Well, problem is I cannot make them work togheter.

To have the dynamic_reconfigure i need to add to the CMakeLists.txt the follwoing

## add dynamic reconfigure api

rosbuild_find_ros_package(dynamic_reconfigure)
include(${dynamic_reconfigure_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake)
gencfg()
rosbuild_add_executable(dynamic_reconfigure_node src/dynamic_reconfigure_node.cpp)

And when I do add this to the CmakeList.txt there is a strange linking error about the camera_info_manager

[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pgrlibdcstereo.dir/src/pgr_conversions.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pgrlibdcstereo.dir/src/pgr_registers.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pgrlibdcstereo.dir/src/pgr_stereocam.o
Linking CXX shared library lib/libpgrlibdcstereo.so
[ 75%] Built target pgrlibdcstereo
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/xb3.dir/src/xb3.o
Linking CXX executable bin/xb3
CMakeFiles/xb3.dir/src/xb3.o: In function `main': xb3.cpp:(.text+0x173d): undefined reference to` camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager::CameraInfoManager(ros::NodeHandle, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

This does not occur when I have the CMakeList.txt without the previous lines.

I initialize camera_info_manager standard like

ros::NodeHandle nh;
CameraInfoManager TEST(nh);

Any hint?

Thanks

Miguel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10108/camera_info_manager/) by [migueloliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/530/migueloliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2011-05-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [migueloliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/530/migueloliveira/) on 2011-05-30**:
I found the problem. I had a problem in the CMakeList.txt. Sorry for the trouble. Its solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem. I had a problem in the CMakeList.txt. Sorry for the trouble. Its solved. - migueloliveira (May 30)

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1